# Deducing $3^f = o(3^g)$ from $f = o(g)$

Tags: asymptotics

I really need help solving the following question:

> Given:
> $$f(n) = o(g(n))$$
>
> Prove:
> $$3^{f(n)} = o(3^{g(n)})$$

My attempt:

I know that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \xrightarrow{} 0 $.

I need to prove that $f(n) - g(n) \xrightarrow{} -\infty$ so that $3^{f(n)-g(n)} \xrightarrow{} 0$.

How do I prove that?

In general, I'm not sure what properties can I assume about $f$ and $g$. Are they positive? What else do I know about them? Are we assuming that all these function approach $\infty$ or can they be $\frac{1}{n}$ etc.?

Comment: You should direct your questions to whoever set you this exercise.

Comment: If we assume that $f,g$ take values in the positive integers, then $f = o(g)$ does imply $f - g \to -\infty$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Isn't it necessary to say that both functions approach $\infty$ in order to say that? And if not, how did you deduce it? I'm self studying this and I'm using material from a friend.

Comment: Is it actually true that all function that take value in the positive integers approach $\infty$ (I can't come up with one that doesn't)

Comment: How about the function $f(n) = 1$? However, if $f = o(g)$ and $f,g$ takes values in the positive integers, then since $f \geq 1$, we must have $g \to \infty$.

Comment: How do you prove that formally? I

Comment: It should follow directly from the definition.

Comment: What if $g$ doesn't have a limit (if that could be possible in integer functions..?) I'm struggling to form a proof like in calculus class.. For example $g = (-1)^n * n^2$ and $f = n$

Comment: I define $f = o(g)$ if $f/g \to 0$. Since $f \geq 1$, if $f/g \to 0$ then also $1/g \to 0$, and so $g \to \infty$ (since $g$ is positive).